# what does this error means "Failed to convert object of type <class 'tuple'> to Tensor"?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a network in Keras and I try to do some changes on the output of a layer and then feed it to the remaining network. in the `apply function` it accepts a tensor with shape (batch size,1,32,32) and all the tensors are in format `channel_first`. then I convolve it with a tensor of shape (8,8,1,64) and the output is (?,64,4,4), but when I want to change the shape to (8,8,4,4) it produces the following error. why does this error happen? because when I try to check code with tensors without a network it works! I add the code here too. could you please tell me what is the problem?

```
    def apply_conv(self, image, filter_type: str):

        if filter_type == 'dct':
            filters = self.dct_conv_weights
        elif filter_type == 'idct':
            filters = self.idct_conv_weights
        else:
            raise('Unknown filter_type value.')
        print(image.shape)

        image_conv_channels = []
        for channel in range(image.shape[1]):
            print(image.shape)
            print(channel)
            image_yuv_ch = K.expand_dims(image[:, channel, :, :],1)
            print( image_yuv_ch.shape)
            print(filters.shape)
            image_conv = Kr.backend.conv2d(image_yuv_ch,filters,strides=(8,8),data_format='channels_first')
            print(image_conv.shape)
            print('salam')
#            image_conv = Kr.backend.permute_dimensions(image_conv,(0, 2, 3, 1))
            image_conv = Kr.backend.reshape(image_conv,(image_conv.shape[0], 8,8,image_conv.shape[2], image_conv.shape[3]))
            print(image_conv.shape)
            image_conv =  Kr.backend.permute_dimensions(image_conv,(0, 1, 3, 2, 4))
            image_conv = Kr.backend.reshape(image_conv,(image_conv.shape[0],
                                                  image_conv.shape[1]*image_conv.shape[2],
                                                  image_conv.shape[3]*image_conv.shape[4]))

#            Kr.backend.expand_dims(image_conv,1)

            # image_conv = F.conv2d()
            image_conv_channels.append(image_conv)

        image_conv_stacked = Kr.backend.concatenate(image_conv_channels, axis=1)

        return image_conv_stacked
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 376, in 
>       decoded_noise=JpegCompression()(act11)#16
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py",
>   line 457, in **call**
>       output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
>
> File "", line 162, in call
>       image_dct = self.apply_conv(noised_image, 'dct')
>
> File "", line 126, in apply_conv
>       image_conv = Kr.backend.reshape(image_conv,(image_conv.shape[0], 8,8,image_conv.shape[2], image_conv.shape[3]))
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py",
>   line 1969, in reshape
>       return tf.reshape(x, shape)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py",
>   line 6482, in reshape
>       "Reshape", tensor=tensor, shape=shape, name=name)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py",
>   line 513, in _apply_op_helper
>       raise err
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py",
>   line 510, in _apply_op_helper
>       preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 1146, in internal_convert_to_tensor
>       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py",
>   line 229, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
>       return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py",
>   line 208, in constant
>       value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py",
>   line 531, in make_tensor_proto
>       "supported type." % (type(values), values))
>
> TypeError: Failed to convert object of type  to Tensor.
>   Contents: (Dimension(None), 8, 8, Dimension(4), Dimension(4)).
>   Consider casting elements to a supported type.